# Accessing overwritten protected member in extended class

Tags: typescript

Let's say that I have a `Base` class an a `Test` class that extends from `Base`. The `Base` class has a protected member, let's say it is an object that stores a dictionary of strings. I wish to overwrite that dictionary in the `Test` class, but somehow, it does not work as intended (at least in my production code, and also when I tested it on [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/hupahatuno/edit?html,js,console,output)):

```js
type ConstantsDict = { [key: string]: string }

abstract class Base {

    protected readonly _constants: ConstantsDict = {
        FOO: 'bar'
    }

    protected get _magicStringFoo(): string {
        return `Base: ${this._constants.FOO}`;
    }

    constructor() {
        // The magic constant FOO is incorrect when invoked in Test
        alert(this._magicStringFoo);
    }
}

class Test extends Base {
    // Overwrite inherited  member
    protected readonly _constants = {
        FOO: 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
    }

    // Overwrite inherited getter
    protected get _magicStringFoo(): string {
        return `Test: ${this._constants.FOO}`;
    }

    // Let's give Test it's own getter for the same magic constant
    private get _magicStringFooPrivate(): string {
        return `Test: ${this._constants.FOO}`;
    }

    constructor() {
        super();

        // The magic constant FOO is correct over here
        alert(`Local magic constant FOO is: ${this._magicStringFooPrivate}`)
    }
}

new Test();
```

The code will alert `Test: bar` instead of `Test: lorem ipsum dolor sit amet`. The good news is that the protected getter inherited from the `Base` class is being overwritten in `Test`, but somehow the `this` reference still points to the incorrect class.

Comment: You have conflated prototypal inheritance. When this code is transpiled into javascript the prototype chain is constructed as if it had been written in JavaScript. Although this looks similar to Java or C# the underlying language does not work that way. Please investigate prototypal inheritance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ordering issue caused by how the constructor functions interact.

Here are the constructors you have based on your code (all other code removed for ease of use).

I have annotated each line with when is called when you instantiate a new `Test`

```
// 3
function Base() { 
    // 4
    this._constants = { 
        // 5
        FOO: 'bar' 
    // 6
    }; 
    // 7 (at this point, FOO is 'bar')
    alert(this._magicStringFoo);
}

// 1
function Test() { 
    // 2
    var _this = _super.call(this) || this; // <-- GO TO SUPER CLASS CONSTRUCTOR
    // 8
    _this._constants = {
        // 9
        FOO: 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'
    // 10
    };
    // 11
    alert("Local magic constant FOO is: " + _this._magicStringFooPrivate);
    //12
    return _this;
}
```

You can see here why the subclass seems to have the wrong value - it just hasn't had the opportunity to overwrite the base class value at that point.

## Fix

My recommended fix would be to pass values to the super class constructor.

Here is a simple version:

```
type ConstantsDict = { [key: string]: string }

abstract class Base {
    constructor(protected magicStringFoo: string) {
        // The magic constant FOO is incorrect when invoked in Test
        alert(this.magicStringFoo);
    }
}

class Test extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super('Test: lorem ipsum dolor sit amet');
    }
}

new Test();
```

I have passed the test string there, but you could pass the `FOO` constant or whatever you need. That solves any ordering problems.

Comment: If that is the case, will there be a workaround for this?

Comment: No. This question derives from a basic misunderstanding of how prototypal inheritance works. The prototype chain hasn't changed just because you desperately want this to work like C# or Java.

Comment: Hi @Terry - I have added my recommended fix. There are other possibilities, like a factory method or temporal coupling... but constructors asking for "what they need" is usually the best answer.